# How to use output of the first function as input for the second function in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Just trying to tinker with the Dart,  a bit.
Here trying to use the Output of the first function ( which is a List) in the second function. but it prints 0, ?

```
void main() {
  print(secondFuncion(firstFuncion()));
}

List firstFuncion() {
  List mylist = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
    mylist.add(i);
  }
  return mylist;
}

secondFuncion(List<mylist> b) {
  for (var element in b) {
    return element;
  }
}
```

Comment: because you're doing it wrong.

Comment: ``secondFuncion`` is retuning a list of values and you're only printing the first value returned by the method. Use a loop to print all the values returned. Or change ``print(secondFuncion(firstFuncion()));`` to ``secondFuncion(firstFuncion());`` and in the second fn ``return element;`` to ``print(element);`` and it should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As @OMI Shah said just change

```
    secondFuncion(List<mylist> b) {
  for (var element in b) {
    return element;
  }
}
```

to this

```
secondFuncion(List b) {
  for (var element in b) {
    print(element);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in the second function as soon as it encounters the first return b[0] exits the function returning only the first element "0".
In order to work you have to return the whole list. I'll give you an example:

```
void main() {
  print(secondFuncion(firstFuncion()));
}

List firstFuncion() {
  List mylist = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
    mylist.add(i);
  }
  return mylist;
}

secondFuncion(List<mylist> b) {
  List mylist2 = [];
  for (var element in b) {
    mylist2.add(element*2);
  }
  return mylist2
}
```

0 2 4 6 8 10....44

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer:

```
void main() {
  secondFuncion(firstFuncion());
}

List firstFuncion() {
  List mylist = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 23; i++) {
    mylist.add(i);
  }
  return mylist;
}

secondFuncion(List b) {
  for (var element in b) {
    print(element);
  }
}
```